# Ruby on Rails: SQLite3 to PostgreSQL null date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, postgresql, date

I am using a SQLite3 database in development, and now have started to use heroku to host my app. Heroku only supports PostgreSQL which I have modified in my GEM file

```
group :development, :test do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Now, everything is working as it should except when I query a date, I get this error

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""
2012-09-12T10:03:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-12T10:03:03+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...-12' AND '2012-09-12' OR DATE(start_date) BETWEEN '' AND '')...
2012-09-12T10:03:03+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2012-09-12T10:03:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     137: <% if @project_search.total_entries > 0 %>
2012-09-12T10:03:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     136: 
2012-09-12T10:03:03+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects"  WHERE (client LIKE '%%' AND industry LIKE '%%' AND role LIKE '%%' AND tech LIKE '%%' AND business_div LIKE '%%' AND project_owner LIKE '%%' AND exception_pm LIKE '%%' AND status LIKE '%%' AND (DATE(start_date) BETWEEN '2011-09-12' AND '2012-09-12' OR DATE(start_date) BETWEEN '' AND '') AND keywords LIKE '%%')):
2012-09-12T10:03:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     138: <% if @search_performed %>
2012-09-12T10:03:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     140: <style>
2012-09-12T10:03:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     139:
```

Here is my project.rb, as I think this is where I need to change something:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :edited_first_name, :edited_last_name, :first_name, :last_name, :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :edited_date, :end_date, :entry_date, :exception_pm, :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech

#validates_presence_of :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :end_date, :exception_pm, :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech



def self.search(search_client, search_industry, search_role, search_tech, search_business_div, search_project_owner, search_exception_pm, search_status, search_start_date_dd, search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B,  search_keywords) 
  return scoped unless search_client.present? || search_industry.present? || search_role.present? || search_tech.present? || search_business_div.present? || search_project_owner.present? || search_exception_pm.present? || search_status.present? || search_start_date_dd.present?  || search_start_date_A.present?  || search_start_date_B.present?  || search_keywords.present?


todays_date = DateTime.now.to_date

if !search_start_date_A.blank? or !search_start_date_B.blank?
    search_start_date_A = Date.parse(search_start_date_A).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    search_start_date_B = Date.parse(search_start_date_B).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    todays_date = ""
    end

if search_start_date_dd.blank?
    todays_date = ""
end


if (search_start_date_A.blank? or search_start_date_B.blank?) and search_start_date_dd.blank?

where(['client LIKE ? AND industry LIKE ? AND role LIKE ? AND tech LIKE ? AND business_div LIKE ? AND project_owner LIKE ? AND exception_pm LIKE ? AND status LIKE ? AND keywords LIKE ?', 
      "%#{search_client}%", "%#{search_industry}%" , "%#{search_role}%" , "%#{search_tech}%" , "%#{search_business_div}%" , 
      "%#{search_project_owner}%" , "%#{search_exception_pm}%" , "%#{search_status}%", 
       "%#{search_keywords}%"
    ])

else

where(['client LIKE ? AND industry LIKE ? AND role LIKE ? AND tech LIKE ? AND business_div LIKE ? AND project_owner LIKE ? AND exception_pm LIKE ? AND status LIKE ? AND (DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ? OR DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND keywords LIKE ?', 
      "%#{search_client}%", "%#{search_industry}%" , "%#{search_role}%" , "%#{search_tech}%" , "%#{search_business_div}%" , 
      "%#{search_project_owner}%" , "%#{search_exception_pm}%" , "%#{search_status}%", 
      search_start_date_dd, todays_date , search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B, "%#{search_keywords}%"
    ])
end
end


def self.paginated_for_index(projects_per_page, current_page)
    paginate(:per_page => projects_per_page, :page => current_page)
  end

end
```

It seems SQLite3 could handle '' as an empty date, but PG can't

Does anyone have some solution to this?

I am new to rails so please remember this when answering. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really wan to use AND in that search? Are all items provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` and `''` (the empty string) are different things. Some databases, like MySQL and apparently SQLite, allow you to treat them as the same thing, but they are not. `''` is not a valid date. PostgreSQL won't accept another common MySQL-ism, `0000-00-00`, either; watch out for that in case you're used to using that as a placeholder or "invalid" value.

You need to fix your application so that it sends `NULL` for null dates. I expect that setting the date to the application-level null/nil value (Ruby seems to use `nil` as its null-value) instead of to `""` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I don't really understand where to edit my code so that the query just doesn't just read `''`

Comment: Instead of `todays_date = ""` write `todays_date = nil`, I expect. I don't really do Ruby/Rails much.

Comment: I would also advise against using different RDBMS in different environments. You may have big surprises when deploying to production later on ... I'd use postgres for development too!

Comment: I had started off using SQLite3, and only just found out that Heroku didn't support it. Seems to be working now.